# Can lokuttara citta's be defined as the true knowing essence (yathabhuta nana dassana)?

Tags: terminology

Can *lokuttara citta's* be defined as the true knowing essence (yathabhuta nana dassana)?

Comment: See also [a good definition of consciousness](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2553/254) and [What is the difference between Vijñāna, Manas and Citta?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1435/254)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, yathābhūtañāṇadassana is said to refer to early stages of Vipassana insight:

> *yathābhūtañāṇadassananti yathāsabhāvajānanasaṅkhātaṃ dassanaṃ. etena taruṇavipassanaṃ dasseti. taruṇavipassanā hi balavavipassanāya paccayo hoti.*
>
> **yathābhūtañāṇadassana** refers to that which is understood as knowing things according to existential characteristics (sabhāva). By this is meant weak (taruṇa) vipassana. And weak vipassana is a requisite for strong (balava) vipassana.
>
> -- SN-a 2.1.3.3

The commentary here is explaining a passage showing the following progression:

> 1. avijjūpanisā saṅkhārā - formations have ignorance as a cause
> 2. saṅkhārūpanisaṃ viññāṇaṃ - consciousness has formations as a cause
> 3. viññāṇūpanisaṃ nāmarūpaṃ - mind and body have consciousness as a cause
> 4. nāmarūpūpanisaṃ saḷāyatanaṃ - the senses have mind and body as a cause
> 5. saḷāyatanūpaniso phasso - contact has the senses as a cause
> 6. phassūpanisā vedanā - sensations have contact as a cause
> 7. vedanūpanisā taṇhā - craving has sensations as a cause
> 8. taṇhūpanisaṃ upādānaṃ - clinging has craving as a cause
> 9. upādānūpaniso bhavo - becoming has clinging as a cause
> 10. bhavūpanisā jāti - birth has becoming as a cause
> 11. jātūpanisaṃ dukkhaṃ - suffering has birth as a cause
> 12. dukkhūpanisā saddhā - confidence has suffering as a cause
> 13. saddhūpanisaṃ pāmojjaṃ - delight has confidence as a cause
> 14. pāmojjūpanisā pīti - rapture has delight as a cause
> 15. pītūpanisā passaddhi - tranquillity has rapture as a cause
> 16. passaddhūpanisaṃ sukhaṃ - happiness has tranquillity as a cause
> 17. sukhūpaniso samādhi - concentration has happiness as a cause
> 18. **samādhūpanisaṃ yathābhūtañāṇadassanaṃ** - knowledge and vision of things as they are has concentration as a cause
> 19. **yathābhūtañāṇadassanūpanisā nibbidā** - disenchantment has knowledge and vision of things as they are as a cause
> 20. nibbidūpaniso virāgo - dispassion has disenchantment as a cause
> 21. virāgūpanisā vimutti - freedom has dispassion as a cause
> 22. vimuttūpanisaṃ khayeñāṇaṃ - knowledge of destruction (of the taints) has freedom as a cause.
>
> -- Upanisa Sutta (SN 12.23)

Balava vipassana refers to nibbida. The lokuttara magga and phala cittas are equated with viraaga and vimutti respectively.

Comment: Bhante, how does confidence have suffering as a cause? Does it mean the understanding of the 1st noble truth causing Sadda in the 3rd and the 4th noble truths or in the Buddha himself who preached about suffering and the end of suffering?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille it causes saddha in the triple gem; suffering shows that the Buddha was right. Without seeing suffering, beings tend to ignore/trivialize the Buddha's teaching.